# How do I resize the view area on my computer monitor in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, aspect-ratio

Currently the display of my screen appears to be wider than the actual view area of my screen. What I want is to get the displayed content, on my desktop to fit available area. How do I achieve this on my windows 7 computer?

**Recommended resolution is 1920 by 1080 pixels for the monitor and that is the current setting. The display is plugged via HDMI. Text size to set to the smallest value. Refresh rate is 60 Hz.**

Comment: Set your desktop resolution to match your monitor's.  See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/change-your-screen-resolution

Comment: Assuming your resolution is correct you could be running into 2 other problems. 1. You need to auto adjust your monitor to sync with the current resolution, all modern monitors have this feature or automatically do it already. 2. Depending on which video-card software you have, you can crop the monitor to fix the screen as well. I suggest you be more specific on your question to get a better answer, cause it currently pretty vague.

Comment: I already set the resolution as suggested and that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: What brand is your video card? What monitor are you using (model number) If it's onboard video, what is the software installed that controls the video, give us more information about you system in your question.

Comment: Using the monitor menu, I reset it to factory settings but to no avail. I also set the adjustment to auto, but that did not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Intel Graphics HD Graphics

Comment: The Monitor itself is not the issue,as I have the same problem going on on my other monitor(both of different makes). The main monitor is a HP HD LCD model TSS-27m

Comment: look for something in here that will fix the problem: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/img/scaling_new.jpg

Comment: I did try the properties on there but none seemed to be the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this. It turned out that the Intel HD Graphics 3000 card I have was the source of the problem. I googled until I found the [reason for the overscan, and info on how to resolve it](http://www.charlestonsw.com/hp-2509m-display-truncating-with-intel-hd-graphics/%20and%20followed). Using [Intel Graphic Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics), I was able to install the correct driver update for my system, rebooted my machine after install completed, and the problem went away.